# Constant audible noise/ whine when CPU is idle

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, noise

I hope this is the right community for asking this question.

I got an **HP ProBook 470 G5** (**i7-8550U**) and it makes a strange noise/ whine ([here are three sound samples](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10D9L_C4DP-lcBTi_Re166vFJRoP5tRWh)).

Since it has no HDD, I think it comes from somewhere on the motherboard and it may have to do with the state of the processor (i.e., in load 40% or higher the sound decreases in intensity).

**Two possible solutions:**

- if I disable `Turbo Boost` in `Bios`, the sound drops considerably
- if I change the settings in `Power Options` -> `Advanced Power Settings` -> `Processor Power Management` -> `Minimum / Maximum processor state` to less than 100% the noise decreases in intensity

However, for both solutions, the score in CPU Mark drops from ~ 8200 to ~ 5500. So, there is performance loss.

**Other mentions:**

- I've tried the latest drivers, both from **HP**, and those from **Intel**
  this is the second **ProBook 470 G5** that has the same problem (i.e., it's actually replacement to the first which I returned for the same reasons mentioned here)
- about two weeks ago I had the same problem with an **Envy 17-ae120nd** with the same type of processor
- my issue seems to be related to this post on the HP forums
- this is [the manual of the product](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05695303) in question

**My questions are:**

- what is causing this noise?
- is this a sign indicating that my laptop is defective?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've had desktops with coil whine for years that worked OK, it was an annoyance.  You may be able to do a like-for-like warranty return with the manufacturer within a short time after purchase.

Comment: Already replaced it. Got a new one with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After listening to the sound samples I'm pretty sure that this is NOT an issue related to the fan on the laptop.

It sounds very much like a grounding issue to do with the audio port.  If its happening on the systems internal speakers I'd say that yes, this is not normal.  If its happening to speakers/headphones you have plugged in it could be an issue with the plug or speakers.

It makes sense that the noises are different depending on the CPU frequency, as you are effectively listening to the rapid changes in power draw which would be caused by the CPU doing stuff.

The problem could be a setting relating to the output device used for sound in your software.  If its not that, its almost certainly a hardware rather then software issue.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I tried to plug in external speakers/ headphones and I even disabled the audio card in device manager. Also, I uninstalled the HP audio drive and used a Windows generic one. The sound remained virtually the same. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Im pretty sure its coil whining and not the audio port. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Classic **coil whining**.

Components most likely on your gfx card starts to vibrate and make a whining irritating sound.

Best explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7HsXHqtxrI

There is basically almost nothing you can do. But watch the video it has some explanations and tips.

Comment: Agreed with you!

Answer (score 1):

this problem is NOT related to audio port.

After some months (with an ASUS and MSI laptops) I figured out.

It really comes when the CPU is overclocked (with TurboBoost) with my current Laptop ASUS TUF504GM with a i7 8750H processor this annoying noise happens, after disabling Turboboost the noise disappear.

In the beginning I was thinking about HDD/SSD, Wifi interference, etc.. but no! It's the freaking turboboost mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the culprit.
I have a 12600K cpu and have the same exact noise, but if I disable C1E, the noise disappear instantly. So C1E is the culprit here.